Exponentiation of power of two by squaring
I am trying to implement exponentiation by squaring of a power of two modulo 2^n − 1.
I do not store the power of two, just its exponent (e.g, 4 = 2^2, the exponent is 2).
For example, I want co compute (2^2)^30 (mod 2^5-1). The correct answer is 1. However, my method below gives wrong result which is 16. The GMP code:
/* input:
    mp_bitcnt_t pos ... the exponent of a base, base = 1 << pos, pos is initially 2 (thus 1 << pos is 4)
    const mpz_t exp ... the exponent for squaring (30)
    mp_bitcnt_t m_exp ... Mersenne number exponent (5) (thus the modulus is 2^5-1)
*/

while (mpz_cmp_ui(exp, 0UL) > 0) { /* exp > 0 */
    if (mpz_odd_p(exp)) { /* exp is odd */
        pos += 1;
    }

    pos = 2 * pos;

    mpz_fdiv_q_2exp(exp, exp, 1); /* exp >>= 1 */

    pos = pos % m_exp;
}

/* the result is 1 << pos */

Where is the error in my code?
I can compute this exponentiation using the mpz_powm method and the answer is correct. However, this is EXTREMELY slow. I want to compute this manually.

For the numbers you're using, you don't need gmp.

@dbush: I am normally working with much bigger numbers.

This might be more of a [math.se] question. Once you determine the mathematics, converting it to code should be straightforward.

Look at the case where exponent is odd. What you do is incorrect in such case. You are telling that (2^(2p+2))^n is equal to (2^p)^(2n+1). In other words that (2p+2)×n = p×(2n+1).

The thing, is, you can't, a priori, find a factorization of 2pn+p other than p(2n+1). And especially not by a factor of n. So there is no value of pos that would simply work with n=(2n+1)>>1.  Usually when people handle power they keep some other factor to keep the "non power of 2" part. That is, instead of trying to, in each step, keep your number in the form of (2^posₖ)^expₖ, which is simply not possible, you keep it in the form ((2^posₖ)^expₖ)×(2^restₖ)

With, initial values being pos₀=pos (intial value of it), exp₀=exp (id), and rest₀=0

When expₖ is even, then, it is as you did: expₖ₊₁ = expₖ/2 ; posₖ₊₁ = 2posₖ ; restₖ₊₁ = restₖ. And when it is odd : expₖ₊₁ = (expₖ-1)/2; posₖ₊₁ = 2posₖ ; restₖ₊₁ + restₖ + posₖ

Of course, all that %m_exp

Thanks to @chrslg, I think I've found the error. I'll post the corrected code.

It turns out that I cannot to modify pos in an odd step, and I have to introduce a separate variable result. The correct code is:
mp_bitcnt_t result = 0;

while (mpz_cmp_ui(exp, 0UL) > 0) {
    if (mpz_odd_p(exp)) {
        result += pos;
        result %= m_exp;
    }

    pos += pos;
    pos %= m_exp;

    mpz_fdiv_q_2exp(exp, exp, 1);
}

/* the result is 1 << result */

